# Grails 2.5 - Is it possible to invoke different actions based on Accept header or format parameter (for the same controller)?

Tags: grails

I have a controller method which is currently mapped on UrlMappings like this:

```
"/api/objects"(controller: 'apiObject',  action: [GET: "list"], parseRequest: true)
```

Which works fine. The list action returns the JSON representation of a list of objects.

What I'd like to do now is, on top of that, add the possibility of having that same list represented as a CSV file.

For instance, I'd like a `'/api/objects'` call to remain to be served by `ApiObjectController#list`, and `'/api/objects?format=csv'` to be served by a different method, such as `ApiObjectController#renderListAsCsv`.

Is it possible to do that, either by using `format=csv` param or `Accept` header?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer your question, I'm sorry. I understand hat you may have reasons outside your control why you are implementing this like that, but just in case you have the freedom to choose, I'm going to try to convince you not to do what you are describing. A Resource has a URL, and the format in which it is returned is just a detail, taking this philosophy into your controller, your resource should be matched to a method in the controller, that should analyze the different options and maybe delegate to helper methods if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional URL mappings based on the `format` query parameter as shown below. But the more common way for rendering the response in a certain format (json, csv, ..) is to use `withFormat`.

```
“/api/objects" {
     format = { params.format }

     controller = “apiObject”
     action = format == ‘csv’ ? renderListAsCsv : list
}
```

The Grails documentation describes how this can be done using [withFormat](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html):

```
class BookController {

    def list() {
        def books = Book.list()

        withFormat {
            html bookList:books
            js { render "alert('hello')" }
            xml { render books as XML }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to reply. Is it possible to use params.format from within the action parameter map? In my example, would it be possible to do something like this? `"/api/objects"(controller: 'apiObject',  action: [GET: format == ‘csv’ ? renderListAsCsv : list], parseRequest: true)`. I've tried something like this but didn't work.

Comment: @felipecao, the mapping logic needs to be within {

Comment: but then can I somehow retrieve the method, as to fully reproduce the mapping logic within the closure? I mean, I would like this to be applied only for GET, but I have other mappings like `POST: "create", PUT: "edit"`, etc, which have been omitted in the original post for the sake of simplicity.